# Voice Recognition onRmsChanged getting value in minus

Tags: android, listener, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to recognize voice. It work but after few seconds it automatically disconnect and giving *rmsvalue -2.12*. If we start reconigation again it giving me an exception:

Here is my MainActivity.class,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
protected long mSpeechRecognizerStartListeningTime = 0;
TextView tvreconizetext;
Button speakButton;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak);
    tvreconizetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvreconizetext);

    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100000);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    SpeechRecognitionListener listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
}

protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.e("tag", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.e("tag", "onBufferReceived :" + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.e("tag", "onEndOfSpeech ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {

        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        } else {
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
        Log.e("tag", "onError :" + error);

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.e("tag", "onEvent :" + eventType + "," + params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.e("tag", "onPartialResults :" + partialResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.e("tag", "onReadyForSpeech :" + params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {

        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        Log.e("matches", "matches ::" + matches.get(0));
        tvreconizetext.setText(matches.get(0));
        mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.e("tag", "onRmsChanged :" + rmsdB);

    }
}

}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSpeak"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Speak" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvreconizetext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bSpeak"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Also i used "RECORD_AUDIO" permission in Manifest.

Here is Exception

> 01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713): Exception in upload
>   method 01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error
>   code: 262182 01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):     at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.io.y.abort(QueueDataSource.java:61)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.i.l.abort(EagerDataSource.java:94)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.i.a.a.e.a(MonitoredCronetRequest.java:169)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.i.a.a.e.a(MonitoredCronetRequest.java:44)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.i.a.a.e$2.a(MonitoredCronetRequest.java:271)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   org.chromium.net.CronetUrlRequest$2.run(CronetUrlRequest.java:579)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.i.x$1.run(TaskRunnerScheduledExecutor.java:36)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 01-02
>   11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   01-02 11:42:39.706: E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838) 01-02 11:42:39.706:
>   E/ChromiumNetwork(6713):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.q$1.run(GsaThreadFactory.java:118)

how can I recognize voice smoothly with recognition listener. If anybody have idea please share it.

Comment: You probably want to to provide the code you wrote.

Comment: And the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for reply @NikolayShmyrev I have updated my question please check

Comment: I need to do speech Recognize for unlimited time,if i'm not speaking anything for 100 seconds then it stop, otherwise it  need to work

Comment: i also tried with your library "pocketsphinx" but didn't success :(

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm developing a continuous listening activity and the same chromium error is displayed in LogCat. Have you managed to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd been messing a lot with my SpeechRecognizer and Audio recording permission code when I got this same problem. I reset my phone and the code worked again by itself. I hope it's that simple for you too. Good luck.

Comment: @NeerajSharma it is possible to "simulate" continuos speech recognition, by relaunching the recognizer as soon as the 100 seconds is reached, or are soon as the recognizer stops because it found a final speech recognition result.